# How do I create a scheduled maintenance alert for GPU VM instances in GCloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, metadata, alert, google-cloud-monitoring

please help with the question:

1. We currently have several GPU VM instances in Gcloud.
2. On each of them, we have a script running in order to be able to find out in advance about the planned maintenance and shutdown, this information is provided by GCloud Metadata an hour before the work is done:
   the query itself:

`curl http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/maintenance-event -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" --silent)`

3. The question is, is it possible to create an alert in GCP for these machines using GCloud monitoring and alerting and how to do it? by means of MQL it is impossible because there is no such metric.

Comment: your question then becomes: "how can i turn the output of arbitrary query to gcloud cli, into the new custom metric".  And then even the more narrow - "How to create a custom metric ?" and here is the answer in docs: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics

Comment: thanks, I'll try and write it off